# Write midi file using mingus in python with two simultaneous instruments

Tags: python, instruments, midi

I am trying to write a composition with several instruments using the mingus library in python. I am first testing the mingus commands using the following code:

```
from mingus.containers import Note
from mingus.containers import NoteContainer
from mingus.containers import Bar
from mingus.containers import Track
from mingus.containers import Composition
from mingus.containers.instrument import MidiInstrument
from mingus.midi import midi_file_out

a=Bar()
a.place_notes("E-4",4)
a.place_notes("G#-3",4)
a.place_notes("A-4",4)
a.place_notes("B-2",4)

i1=MidiInstrument()
i1.instrument_nr=9
i2=MidiInstrument()
i2.instrument_nr=71

t1=Track(i1)
t1.add_bar(a)
t2=Track(i2)
t2.add_bar(a)

midi_file_out.write_Track("t1.mid",t1)
midi_file_out.write_Track("t2.mid",t2)
```

This creates 2 midi files, each playing a different instrument. Then I tried using:

```
c=Composition()
c.add_track(t1)
c.add_track(t2)
midi_file_out.write_Composition("c.mid",c)
```

When I print c I get this list:

```
[ ['C-0' - 'B-8'], [[[0.0, 4, ['E-4']], [0.25, 4, ['G#-3']], [0.5, 4, ['A-4']], [0.75, 4, ['B-2']]]]][ ['C-0' - 'B-8'], [[[0.0, 4, ['E-4']], [0.25, 4, ['G#-3']], [0.5, 4, ['A-4']], [0.75, 4, ['B-2']]]]]
```

But the midi file only plays the last track/instrument.

How could I play two tracks with different instruments at the same time?

Comment: I just tried out your code and it generated "c.mid", which I opened in MuseScore on my MacBook Pro, and all tracks/instruments were there and played. What are you using to play the midi file?